# tag people inside answer

Tags: support

Is there a way to add people and thank them inside answers? In [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/209734/how-is-lp-calculated/209741#209741) question I wanted to thank TimB for improving my answer but writing "Thanks to .." didn't seem correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't (other than by typing there @name, but this won't notify them).

In general though, thanks are not required. We like to keep the signal-to-noise ratio high here, so anything that detracts from the content of the post is discouraged.

Comment: Basically we hate fun, and anything tangentially related :-)

Comment: Ok I'm deleting the thanks part then.

Comment: btw typing @name doesn't work in answers. it works in comments

Comment: @Furkan it only works when addressing the answerer or another user who has commented on that specific post, however.

Comment: Comment me in your answer then

Comment: You can also look into the [site chat room,](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) and post a thank you there.